# Records the specific bandwith on GNU Radio

Tags: signal-processing, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, software-defined-radio

[flowgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZk4l.png).I just started to struggle with GNU radio with using adalm-pluto. I aim to record the 2MHz interval in FM broadcast. I tried to below flow which try to record the fm broadcast. But when i converted the output of the file sink to wav file with SoX and opened in SDR#, it just shows the -19kHz and +19kHz on selected frequency(like 87.5MHz,88,4 MHz, etc…). I want to record at 2MHz interval. I mean if beginning of the frequency is 87.5 MHz, I want to record whole radios between 87.5 MHz and 89.5 MHz. Is that possible in GNU radio? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to connect File Sink block immediately after PlutoSDR. If you choose LO 100 MHz and sample rate 2 Mhz, it will translate RF spectrum 99-101 MHz to baseband.